# Access denied when using OAuth client credentials flow to create shared mailbox

Tags: exchange-basicauth

**Short version:**

How to correctly set up application permissions and/or role assignments and/or something else that I'm missing, so that application id/secret (OAuth client credentials) can be used to create shared mailboxes?

So far I've tried couple combinations of permissions/roles, e.g. `Exchange.ManageAsApp` with User Administrator (`fe930be7-5e62-47db-91af-98c3a49a38b1`), Exchange administrator (`29232cdf-9323-42fd-ade2-1d097af3e4de`) and bunch of other.

**Details:**

I have a bunch of powershell scripts used to automate various tasks on Exchange Online. So far I've been using basic auth, which I was able to successfully convert into OAuth password flow.

But to get rid of dependency on service account completely, I'd prefer to use credentials flow. In background I'm trying to do something like this:

```cs
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}", false, _tokenCache);
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(ClientId, ClientSecret);
var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Resource, clientCredential);
var username = "OAuthUser@" + TenantId;
var password = authenticationResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
var executor = new ExolExecutor(username, password);
await executor.Execute(Script, cancellationToken);
```

where executor does the regular thing:

1. Create PSSession to `https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid?BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=true`
2. Executes powershell script using

   ```
   using PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
   powershell.Runspace = runspace;
   powershell.AddScript(script);
   ...
   await Task.Factory.FromAsync(powershell.BeginInvoke(input, output), powershell.EndInvoke);
   ```
3. Remove PSSession

So far so good. Works perfectly fine with `Get-Mailbox -ResultSize 1`.
But when trying to create new shared mailbox `New-Mailbox -Name "pko222" -DisplayName "pko222" -Alias "pko222" -Shared`, I'm getting

```
CategoryInfo.Activity: New-Mailbox
CategoryInfo.Category: 1001
CategoryInfo.Reason: ADOperationException
CategoryInfo.TargetName: 
CategoryInfo.TargetType: 
ErrorDetails.Message: 
ErrorDetails.RecommendedAction: 
Exception.Message: Active Directory operation failed on DB7PR01A03DC005.EURPR01A003.prod.outlook.com. This error is not retriable. Additional information: Access is denied.
Active directory response: 00000005: SecErr: DSID-03152612, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0

FullyQualifiedErrorId: [Server=BEXP281MB0087,RequestId=88419a8e-78a4-4967-9bca-71d40feb5150,TimeStamp=10/6/2020 11:57:38 AM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ADOperationException] 2C0312E5,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewMailbox
```

JWT token looks something like this:

```json
{
    "aud": "https://outlook.office365.com",
    "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy/",
    "iat": 1601985127,
    "nbf": 1601985127,
    "exp": 1601989027,
    "aio": "E2RgYFCOsw1iZj34elV49CH5zyd5AQ==",
    "app_displayname": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "appid": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "appidacr": "1",
    "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy/",
    "oid": "zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz",
    "rh": "0.AAAAv9y4fwZQ_0G6_d1kLKJ_sarAXb_REQFHhc2EM1FNn9tIAAA.",
    "roles": ["User.Read.All", "full_access_as_app", "Mail.ReadWrite", "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite", "User.ReadBasic.All", "Mailbox.Migration", "Mail.Read", "Mail.Send", "MailboxSettings.Read", "Exchange.ManageAsApp"],
    "sid": "qqqqqqqq-qqqq-qqqq-qqqq-qqqqqqqqqqqq",
    "sub": "zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz",
    "tid": "yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "uti": "CRytfXbD80y3ATmQvd-VAQ",
    "ver": "1.0",
    "wids": ["29232cdf-9323-42fd-ade2-1d097af3e4de", "88d8e3e3-8f55-4a1e-953a-9b9898b8876b", "fe930be7-5e62-47db-91af-98c3a49a38b1", "9360feb5-f418-4baa-8175-e2a00bac4301", "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10", "0997a1d0-0d1d-4acb-b408-d5ca73121e90"]
}
```

Comment: Hello, i'm facing the same problem, did you have any success since then ?

Answer (score 0):

Fyi i managed to make it work on my side.
you just need to add the following param in the connection uri

```
&email=SystemMailbox{bb558c35-97f1-4cb9-8ff7-d53741dc928c}@yourtenantname.onmicrosoft.com
```

so the connection uri looks like :

```
https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell-LiveId?BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=true&email=SystemMailbox{bb558c35-97f1-4cb9-8ff7-d53741dc928c}@yourtenantname.onmicrosoft.com
```

just change the suffix from 'yourtenantname' with ... your tenant name! dont put the tenant guid !

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/451006/pssession-and-modern-auth.html